# combining UIImageView with UIView and save it as a Image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I am writing a small app that takes a photo and do modifications to it. There is a feature to put stickers(images) on top of the taken photo. I want the user to be abel to pinch rotate and drag the stickers so I used a UIImageView to contain the image so that I could use gesture functions to modify it.

But here is the problem, after the user finished modifying the stickers, how could I save the photo with the sticker? They are in different views and the only thing I can think of is to keep track of the modifications to the stickers and draw them on the photo after the user finished modifying it. Is there a easier way? What should I do?

```
func addSticker(name: String)
{
    var stickerModView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(blah blah))
    var sticker = UIImage(named:"blah blah.png")
    stickerModView.image = sticker
    self.view.addSubview(stickerMod)

    var tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    var pinchRec = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()
    var rotateRec = UIRotationGestureRecognizer()
    var panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    pinchRec.addTarget(self, action: Selector("pinchedView:"))
    rotateRec.addTarget(self, action: Selector("rotatedView:"))
    panRec.addTarget(self, action: Selector("draggedView:"))
    tapRec.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tappedView:"))

    stickerModView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRec)
    stickerModView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateRec)
    stickerModView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
    stickerModView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    stickerModView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your complete `UIImageView` with editing, you can try this,

```
    let rect : CGRect = CGRect() //Your view size from where you want to make UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    let context : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let img : UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //your image ready to save in img
```

It may help you!!

Comment: This works! But one problem though, how could I specified the location of the begin image context?

Comment: How are you placing a Image `stickerModView(sticker)` on view, you can get reference frame of that UIImageView.

Comment: You can set limited area, in which user has to edit image and make sticker, so every-time, you have to set image crop area to that.

Comment: it works really well, however the image quality is very low, how can I fix that?